# Searching for a 2D Array Pattern using Recursion in a Dataset

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

Can someone please make some suggestions on a better way to search for a pattern in a CSV table/dataset using javascript?

```
var dataset= [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]];
var pattern = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]];
arrex(dataset, pattern, 0, 0);

arrex = function(dataset, pattern, row, column) {
  if(dataset[row][column] == pattern[row][column] || patern[row][column] == "_") { // _ is the dont care case
    if(dataset[row].length-1 == column && dataset.length-1 == row){ 
      return true; // final case everything matched!!
    } else if (dataset[row].length > column+1) {
      return arrex(dataset, pattern, row, column+1); 
    } else {
      return arrex(dataset, pattern, row+1, 0); // check next row
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Any suggestions would be awesome... I'm particularly interested in converting the array to a string and then doing a string comparison.

Comment: Pattern is same size of dataset and contains 0, 1 or "_", right? Is the dataset always two-dimensional?

Comment: Typically the dataset is larger then the pattern to be detected... i was thinking of writing a different function to index through the dataset... do you have any suggestions on parsing a larger dataset into chunks that can then be searched for patterns?

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming the pattern is same size of dataset and contains 0, 1 or "_", it's a one liner:

```
var dataset= [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]];
var pattern = [[0, 0, 0], ["_", 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]];

var match= dataset.join('').test(new RegExp('^' + pattern.join('').replace(/_/, '.') + '$'));

console.log(match);
```

Comment: Thanks... let me try that out... what if I was looking to find the X,Y coordinates of the pattern inside a larger dataset?